# How to test a xml files during maven(3) test phase

Tags: unit-testing, maven-3

Is there any way to perform a basic test/unittest for a xml file included in a module?

E.g. I like to "lint" test my persistence.xml or check if the schema to a xml-file is valid.

Comment: What about [xml-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/) ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Since I wasn't aware something like this existed. Thanks for pointing towards it. :)

Comment: @khmarbaise why don't you supply this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the [xml-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/)

It could be that the links will become invalid cause codehaus is shutting down it's services so you can take a look at https://github.com/mojohaus/xml-maven-plugin.